# javascript: Send base64string direct to print without preview

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, base64

I am using ASP.Net MVC with jquery and javascript.

I am getting base64string as per my code in ajax success everything is running fine but I want to pass that base64string directly to print without preview.

I am opening the pdf like this and want to send data.bytedata direct to print without preview using window.open. But when I use window.open it render me the  current whole web page from where my operation is running.

```
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + data.bytedata);
```

I have read so many articles with [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) as well but I am confuse with pdf.js that it will work with chrome or not and direct print is possible using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to open it inside iframe with using window.open if it doesn't open directly.

```
window.open("<iframe src='data:application/pdf;base64, " + encodeURI(data.bytedata) + "'></iframe>")
```

You can read whole article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46702929/show-base64-pdf-data-using-window-open-on-chrome-new-version/50845043)