# Show base64 pdf data using window.open on chrome new version

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, pdf

I am using following code for open base64 data as pdf in new window

```
var pdf=response.data.base64;       
var doc = document.createElement("a");
doc.href ='data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + pdf;
doc.target = "blank";
doc.click();
$window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,' + pdf);
```

This is working fine for chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 
but not working in version 61.0.3163.100 [Refer screenshot]
[Sample plunker code](https://plnkr.co/edit/tv3Cma?p=preview)

[image]

Answer (score 20):

```
var pdfResult = response.data.base64;
                    
let pdfWindow = window.open("")
pdfWindow.document.write("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " + encodeURI(pdfResult) + "'></iframe>")
```

this serves to display the base64 pdf in a browser tab.

Comment: Please translate your answer to English

Comment: I think data_.data.info.result.result in the above answer is confusing. For whoever trying to implement above solution to open base64 PDF in new tab, simply replace the data_.data.info.result.result as below:


pdfResult = [your base64 PDF string]

Answer (score 7):

I faced similar issue using AngularJS. This is how I have managed, in my case I load the file from URL as arraybuffer. Hope it helps.

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/transaction-file/'+id,
    responseType:'arraybuffer'
}).then(function(response){
    var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);
}, function(response){
    //Error
});
```

Comment: I much prefer this solution as it allows for downloading the pdf file from the pdf viewer and it also looks better as it open full window size where the iframe method has the default body padding in it. And it can be easily adapted to work from a base64 string instead of a arrayBuffer.

Comment: I like this solution too but the URL will look a bit ugly `blob:http://127.0.0.1:8080/afdc2815-85dd-4686-9be1-57763887dbeb`

Comment: I get an empty pdf file

Answer (score 3):

I have me too problem and my solution with my friend Petrus is:

```
const win = window.open("","_blank");
let html = '';

html += '<html>';
html += '<body style="margin:0!important">';
html += '<embed width="100%" height="100%" src="data:application/pdf;base64,'+base64+'" type="application/pdf" />';
html += '</body>';
html += '</html>';

setTimeout(() => {
  win.document.write(html);
}, 0);
```